# set movieclip-size in actionscript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript

i'd like to load an external image in a movieclip via

```
  createEmptyMovieClip(..)
  mcName.loadMovie( imageName )
```

trying to set the mc-size via

```
  mcName._width = 100
  mcName._height = 100
```

nothing changes.
furthermore - any possibilities to zoom or stretch the image to get the size provided from the mc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the movie is done loading.  You can use getBytesLoaded and getBytesTotal to make sure it's complete.  Or better yet, use [the MovieClipLoader class](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html#main_Using_the_ActionScript_2_0_MovieClipLoader_class).

Once the loaded image appears on the stage, _height and _width should return the boundaries of what is visible. Unless of course, you set them to another value, which will stretch or compress the image.